Style for visitor counter React.js
I want to create visitor counter for my website. I use api to get hit counter. I want to create something like this

I try with code below but the result like this

I want to ask what I need to do to make it like the design I want. what code that I did wrong?
function Card(props:any) {
  const count = `${props.number}`.split('');
 
  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
      {count.map((val) => (
        <div
          style={{
            fontSize: 42,
            marginRight: 10,
            background: "#8D0000",
            color: "white",
            width: 40,
            height: 55,
            fontWeight: "bold",
            textAlign: "center"
          }}
        >
          {val}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

const Footer = () => {
  const [visitor, setvisitor] = useState<visitortype>();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://count.cab/hit/ghG6Oirn0b')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(allvisitor=>  console.log(allvisitor))
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }, []);

 return (
    <GridItem
      w="100%"
      h={{ base: "80px", lg: "300px" }}
      colSpan={{ base: 8, lg: 4 }}
    >
      <VStack
        align={{ base: "center", lg: "stretch" }}
        marginTop={{ base: "0", lg: "60px" }}
        marginLeft={{ base: "0", lg: "50px" }}
      >
       <Card number={visitor?.count}/>

      </VStack>
    </GridItem>
  );
};


I also try using react-flip-number but still not like the style I want

<FlipNumbers 
  height={25} 
  width={20}  
  color="white" 
  background="#8D0000"
  numberStyle={{
    fontSize: 16,
  }}
  play perspective={100} 
  numbers={`${visitor?.count ?? 0}`}
/>;


This usually indicates that val is an object and not a string. Log the value of allvisitor in your useEffect to make sure you have the correct data

Could you give me example where or how to ?

Replace setvisitor(allvisitor) with console.log(allvisitor) in your code. Then check the browser console and past the output in your question

sorry how to past the output ?

Sorry, I meant paste the output in your question

this is the result from console {
"count": 661,
"click": 661
}

Sorry i still dont understand what you mean

Reflection to your question
The error, I believe, stems from a misunderstanding of how component parameter passing works. You thought that simply declaring the parameter passed to the component is sufficient. It's not. The component receives an object containing all the passed properties, including the one named "value" in your case. So, if you continue this way, you'll find it a bit awkward to access the value parameter from the object using value.value.
<Card value={577} />

// Now "value" is a object, what stored a properties (as "value={577}" attribute)
const Card = (value) => {
  // Now can get "value" attribute from "value" object - not readable
  console.log(value.value) // 577
}

Solution
In React.js, components receive passed variables as an object. You can either declare the object directly (e.g., as props) and reference its parameters later, or declare the parameters directly as shown in the second example.
<Card number={577} anotherProp={true} />

function Card(props) {
  // Can use properties as parameter of props object
  console.log(props.number) // 577
  console.log(props.anotherProp) // true
}

// or

function Card({ number, anotherProp }) {
  // Can use properties when directly declared them in function
  // That's called "Destructuring assignment"
  console.log(number) // 577
  console.log(anotherProp) // true
}

More information

Destructuring assignment - MDN Docs
props inside the child component - React.js Docs

Example


// Import the React and ReactDOM modules
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

// The component receives the passed values as object (props)
function Card(props) {
  const digits = `${props.number}`.split('');
 
  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
      {digits.map((val) => (
        <div
          style={{
            fontSize: 42,
            marginRight: 10,
            background: "#8D0000",
            color: "white",
            width: 40,
            height: 55,
            fontWeight: "bold",
            textAlign: "center"
          }}
        >
          {val}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

// Instead of declaring the object (props), you can directly declare the parameters within { and }
// That's called "Destructuring assignment"
function AnotherCard({ number }) {
  const digits = `${number}`.split('');
 
  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
      {digits.map((val) => (
        <div
          style={{
            fontSize: 42,
            marginRight: 10,
            background: "#8D0000",
            color: "white",
            width: 40,
            height: 55,
            fontWeight: "bold",
            textAlign: "center"
          }}
        >
          {val}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

// App component
function App() {
  return (
    <div style={{ display: "grid", gap: "10px" }}>
      Example #1 (Card component with props object)
      <Card number={577} />
      
      Example #2 (AnotherCard component with destructuring assignment)
      <AnotherCard number={688} />
    </div>
  );
}

// Render the application to the DOM
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-dom/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>



Example with API


// Import the React and ReactDOM modules
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

// The component receives the passed values as object (props)
function Card(props) {
  const digits = `${props.number}`.split('');
 
  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
      {digits.map((val) => (
        <div
          style={{
            fontSize: 42,
            marginRight: 10,
            background: "#8D0000",
            color: "white",
            width: 40,
            height: 55,
            fontWeight: "bold",
            textAlign: "center"
          }}
        >
          {val}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

// Instead of declaring the object (props), you can directly declare the parameters within { and }
// That's called "Destructuring assignment"
function AnotherCard({ number }) {
  const digits = `${number}`.split('');
 
  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
      {digits.map((val) => (
        <div
          style={{
            fontSize: 42,
            marginRight: 10,
            background: "#8D0000",
            color: "white",
            width: 40,
            height: 55,
            fontWeight: "bold",
            textAlign: "center"
          }}
        >
          {val}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

// App component
function App() {
  // Declare visitor with default object
  const [visitor, setVisitor] = useState({
    count: 0,
    click: 0
  });

  // Request data of visitor
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://count.cab/hit/ghG6Oirn0b')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(v =>  setVisitor(v));
  }, []);
  
  // Will see that the code runs first, and the fetch will update the visitor value asynchronously
  console.log(visitor)

  return (
    <div style={{ display: "grid", gap: "10px" }}>
      Example #1 (Card component with props object)
      <Card number={visitor.count} />
      
      Example #2 (AnotherCard component with destructuring assignment)
      <AnotherCard number={visitor.count} />
    </div>
  );
}

// Render the application to the DOM
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-dom/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>



Example with API & extra zero digits


// Import the React and ReactDOM modules
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

// How many digits in total do we want to display
const DIGIT_COUNT = 5

// The component receives the passed values as object (props)
function Card(props) {
  let digits = `${props.number}`.split('');
  // Determine the number of digits
  const numDigits = digits.length;
  // If the number has less than DIGIT_COUNT digits, add leading zeros
  if (numDigits < DIGIT_COUNT) {
    digits = Array(DIGIT_COUNT - numDigits).fill(0).concat(digits);
  }

  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
      {digits.map((val, index) => (
        <div
          key={index}
          style={{
            fontSize: 42,
            marginRight: 10,
            background: "#8D0000",
            color: "white",
            width: 40,
            height: 55,
            fontWeight: "bold",
            textAlign: "center"
          }}
        >
          {val}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

// Instead of declaring the object (props), you can directly declare the parameters within { and }
// That's called "Destructuring assignment"
function AnotherCard({ number }) {
  let digits = `${number}`.split('');
  // Determine the number of digits
  const numDigits = digits.length;
  // If the number has less than DIGIT_COUNT digits, add leading zeros
  if (numDigits < DIGIT_COUNT) {
    digits = Array(DIGIT_COUNT - numDigits).fill(0).concat(digits);
  }

  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
      {digits.map((val, index) => (
        <div
          key={index}
          style={{
            fontSize: 42,
            marginRight: 10,
            background: "#8D0000",
            color: "white",
            width: 40,
            height: 55,
            fontWeight: "bold",
            textAlign: "center"
          }}
        >
          {val}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

// App component
function App() {
  // Declare visitor with default object
  const [visitor, setVisitor] = useState({
    count: 0,
    click: 0
  });

  // Request data of visitor
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://count.cab/hit/ghG6Oirn0b')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(v =>  setVisitor(v));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div style={{ display: "grid", gap: "10px" }}>
      Example #1 (Card component with props object)
      <Card number={visitor.count} />
      
      Example #2 (AnotherCard component with destructuring assignment)
      <AnotherCard number={visitor.count} />
    </div>
  );
}

// Render the application to the DOM
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-dom/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>




Is it working if the data from API?

The origin of the data does not matter.  Just a way of passing it to a component.

i update my code above but result still undefined did i miss something?

@Estherak23 Ah, I see the provided API link is working. We don't like external sources on SO because if they disappear, the examples won't work anymore. But at the end of my answer, I'll insert some code that works only with your API.

@Estherak23 updated with two example (first: just get number by API, second: add extra zeros)

Since you are accessing props in card component, you need to modify the result variable like this:
const result = `${value.value}`.split("");

If not, then you need to modify the way you access props and use object destructuring like:
const Card = ({value}) => {}


i change it but result become undefinied

I think it should be value.count or value.click according to the log.

still not working
